# How to remove space (margin) that between QMainWindow and mdiArea?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a `QMainWindow` and I have inserted `mdiArea` in the main window.
You must first see the following image:

[image]

As you seen the gray area is `mdiArea` and the spaces(margin) that between main window and `mdiArea` are what I want to remove it.
I have used `setContentsMargins` function, but does not do anything.

**How can I remove these spaces ?**

I want to be like the following image:
[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`QMainWindow` has a **central widget** that has a layout. The layout you use on `QMainWindow` is should be used upon its central widget instead. Hence you have to call

[`QWidget* QMainWindow::centralWidget()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget) first,

so you can get the central widget first and then use

[`void QLayout::setContentsMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins)

to adjust its layout. The diagram below comes from Qt's documentation.

[image]
[image]

Creating a main window ***without a central widget is not supported***. You must have a central widget even if it's just a placeholder.

---

For example, you could have the following in `QMainWindow`'s constructor:

```
centralWidget()->layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
statusBar()->hide();
ui->mainToolBar->hide();
```

[image]

The **status bar** and the **tool bar** have been hidden, in order to remove as much **blank space** as possible.

Comment: I have wrote this code in the constructor of MainWindow. but unfortunately, still does not want to remove the spaces.

Comment: @LionKing What do you mean "doesn't want to remove the spaces"? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @LionKing OK I've edited my post, need to call centralWidget first and get it's layout.

Comment: Yes, that's it. but can you please what the mean of `central widget`?

Comment: @LionKing It's the base widget of QMainWindow, I'll update the post and provide detail in a minute.